# How to Alter Varchar Type Column to Date Type Column without Loosing the data

Tags: mysql

In my datatable there is a column named 'journeydate' which is Varchar Type and its containing data as DD/MM/YYYY format, Now what I require at the moment is I want to convert varchar type to Date Type Column with Same data but in YY-mm-DD format.

How Can we do this without Loosing existing data.

Screenshot of Database Table:
[image: Screenshot of Database Table]

Comment: Column of type `Date` has no format. Once you have the data in Date column you can print it in any format you like.

Comment: but how can  we alter this column to date column without loosing the data.

Comment: Did you try `Alter' statement for this?

Comment: if we alter all data in this column is 0000-00-00 .

Comment: @gauravsingh I've answered you question you can check that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conversion:

```
update tbl set jdate=str_to_date(journeydate, '%d/%m/%Y');
```

You should do the conversion in three steps:

1. Create a column of type `date` (e. g. `jdate`)
2. fill the column with values from current `journeydate` column. (Use the conversion I posted above.)
3. You can now rename the two columns once you have established that none of your queries still relies on `journeydate` being of type varchar.

As an optional last step you can then delete the obsolete varchar column. I would keep it for a while in order to check for possible conversion errors.